# Generators of the congruence subgroup $\Gamma (5) \subset SL(2,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modular-forms

Recall that $SL(2,\mathbb Z)=\left\{A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}: \det(A)=1; a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z \right\} $ and $\Gamma(5)=\left\{A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}: \det(A)=1; a\equiv d\equiv \pm1, b \equiv c\equiv0  \right\}$. What are the generators of $\Gamma(5)$? Does anyone have a reference for this?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2757/generators-for-congruence-subgroups-of-sl-2

Comment: @QuinnGreicius how does this answer my question?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question. If it did, I would have posted it as an answer. What it does do is provide some potentially useful references.

Comment: I've already checked this out and unfortunately I was not able to find anything promising.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: The MO question cited by @QuinnGreicius does answer your question, see the references in Ignat Soroko's answer. Of course, it is faster to use Sage than dig up a 1933 article :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a one-liner in Sage (try the [online calculator](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/)): if you type

```
Gamma(5).generators()
```

then you get the response

```
[
[1 5]  [-24   5]  [-109   40]  [11 -5]  [-39  25]  [ 6 -5]  [-64 105]
[0 1], [ -5   1], [ -30   11], [20 -9], [-25  16], [ 5 -4], [-25  41],

[ 11 -20]  [-89 235]  [ 16 -45]  [ 21 -80]
[  5  -9], [-25  66], [  5 -14], [  5 -19]
]
```

(This is a slightly different $\Gamma(5)$ than yours, since Sage's definition of $\Gamma(5)$ requires that $a = d = 1 \bmod(5)$, not just $\pm 1$, but that's easily rectified by adding $-1$ to the generator list.)

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!